# Is there a way to use directories in html?

Tags: html

I am trying to write a simple HTML page and I want to put my css and my favicon in another folder, put this does not work.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../other/home.ico" />
<link rel=stylesheet href="../other/home.css" />
```

when I use this code, it doesnt find the right file even though i think it is the right way to write it.

my HTML file is in the folder:  (E:\website\transendence)       while my css and favicon is in: (E:\website\other)

Comment: What is your main url ?

Comment: @ttrasn my man url? i guess it is E:\website

Comment: yes. like `localhost` or like `localhost/website` or  ?

Comment: my main url is E\website

Comment: i solved it ty guys